# Switching themes using Less + CSS Modules in React

Tags: css, reactjs, less, themes, css-modules

In my project, I use CSS Modules with Less, which means I get the best of both worlds.

My `src` folder looks something like this:

```
components/
    [all components]
theme/
    themes/
        lightTheme.less
        darkTheme.less
    palette.less
```

**palette.less**:

```css
@import './themes/lightTheme.less';
```

Then, in every component that wants to use colors from the theme, I do:

**component.module.less**:

```css
@import '../../theme/palette.less';

.element {
    background-color: @primary;
}
```

This structure lets me edit `palette.less` to import the theme I want to use. The thing is that **I want to let the users choose their preferred theme** on their own. Themes should be switchable on runtime, which means I somehow need to have both themes compiled.

---

I imagine the perfect solution to be something like this:

**app.less**

```css
body {
    @theme: @light-theme;

    &.dark-theme {
        @theme: @dark-theme;
    }
}
```

And then somehow import this `@theme` variable in every component and read properties from it (i.e. `@theme[primary]`).

Unfortunately, Less variables scoping don't work like this.

---

I am open-minded to any solution that uses Less modules.

Thank you!

Comment: you should add @include before light-theme

Comment: @Ranjithv That's just some pseudo-code to demonstrate what I was thinking of

Comment: You should look at css variables https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: The best solution is `css in js` like styled-components, emotion etc.. then using a `ThemeProvider` it's easy to switch multiple themes programatically

Comment: Ahalan @gaditzkhori, we don't want to use styled-components because it makes our CSS way more messy (those `.styled.js` files, everything is a component except they're absolutely not...)

Comment: Are you using webpack ?

Comment: @MohamedRamrami yes

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/klimashkin/css-modules-theme/blob/master/README.md#theming ?

Comment: Or https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/blob/master/docs/theming.md ?

Answer (score 3):

I know that you've probably looking for a solution that uses Less / CSS modules, but it's very likely that your situation can be solved solely with the use of css variables (as Morpheus commented on your question).

#### How it would work?

You'd have to ensure all your styling does not use hardcoded values, i.e. instead of:

```
.awesome-div {
  background-color: #fefefe;
}
```

You would have:

```
:root {
  --awesome-color: #fefefe;
}

.awesome-div {
  background-color: var(--awesome-color);
}
```

#### Changing between light and dark

There are two ways of changing themes in this approach:

- Use vanilla Js code within React to update the `:root` CSS element, check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ludanin/pen/RwNqqab?editors=0110) for more information;
- Just load a component containing all new `:root` variables in its component.css file;

In React (in vanilla CSS too) you can easily have multiple components/elements declaring their own `:root` at their .css files.

Furthermore, any new `:root` will overwrite conflicting values from previous `:root`. For example if at file app.css we have `:root { --color: red; }` and, when loading another component, component A for instance, where in component_a.css we have the same variable overwritten, e.g. `:root { --color: blue; }` the one rendered in our browsers will be the one from component A.

Following this logic, you can have a dummy component that does and renders exactly nothing, but instead in this component.js file you import the .css of a theme, e.g.:

```
import './light.css'; // suppose this is the light-theme dummy component
```

When switching themes in your app you'd just have to remove the dummy component from scene and call the other one.

I'm not too experienced with codepen to the point of providing you an example containing imports/modules over there, but I hope the above explanation can give you an idea of what I mean. Still, here's a brief pseudo-code of what I'm intending to demonstrate:

```
loadTheme() {
  if (this.state.theme === 'dark') return <LightTheme />;
  if (this.state.theme === 'user-3232') return <UserTheme />;
  return <DarkTheme />;
}

render() {
  return (
    <App>
      {this.loadTheme()}
      <OtherContent>
    </App>
  );
}
```

Comment: CSS Variables is a cool solution but it eliminates the option for me to have value manipulations such as fading a color.

Comment: You can declare your css variables in a .less file and use value manipulations

Comment: You can simulate fading colors with CSS variables as well; I actually do this a lot in production, i.e. declaring `--fade-me: 200, 215, 225` then using this variable as it follows: `border-color: rgba(var(--fade-me), 0.2)`. It's not as straightforward as using a CSS pre-processor, but it allows me to keep a relatively organized CSS codebase compared to what I expected it would be. Still, if in your project you rely too much on Less then I'd recommend stick with it, I'll leave my answer here since somebody using plain CSS might benefit from it. BTW, I hope that you find a solution here.

Comment: I don't see how the example with "import the theme" would work. The import of the theme will import the css at build time, and the last one will win.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use css variables, an easy option is to use the [react-theme-change](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-theme-change) library.

example:

themes.ts

```
import ReactThemeChange from 'react-theme-change';

const base = {
    btn_radius: '50%',
};

const themes = {
    dark: {
        bg_0: 'rgba(21, 14, 65, 1)',
        title: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
    },
    light: {
        bg_0: 'rgba(239, 242, 247, 1)',
        title: 'rgba(42, 49, 60, 1)',
    },
    gray: {
        bg_0: 'rgba(35, 42, 63, 1)',
        title: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
    },
};
const useThemeChange = ReactThemeChange({
    base,
    themes,
    defaultTheme: 'light',
});

export default useThemeChange;
```

styles

```
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: var(--btn_radius);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.demo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--bg_0);
  color: var(--title);
}

.themeName {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.btns {
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
}
```

switch

```
import React from 'react';

import useThemeChange from './themes';
import './App.scss';

function App() {
    const {theme, setTheme} = useThemeChange();

    return (
        <div className="demo">
            <div className="themeName">current theme: {theme.name}</div>
            <div className="btns">
                <button onClick={() => setTheme('dark')}>dark</button>
                <button onClick={() => setTheme('light')}>light</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Styled components, it can do that.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components

https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming

I did it myself as a Easter Egg in an app of mine, so I know for sure it works. Unfortunately it is closed so I can't show you the code publicly.

Comment: As I said in the comments, we don't want to use styled-components because it makes our CSS way messier (those .styled.js files, everything is a component except they're absolutely not...)

Comment: You don't have to use .styled.js files if you don't want to.
Also, you can create *one* styled component with all your styling in it if it's what you prefer. You can then wrap your app around this component, and keep the CSS in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import navStyle from './navbar.module.css';
import './assets/css/global.css';


export default function Navbar() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');

  const handleTheme = () => {
    var root = document.querySelector(':root');
    var rootStyle = getComputedStyle(root);

    if(rootStyle.getPropertyValue('--Forground--') === 'black'){
      root.style.setProperty('--Forground--', 'white');
      root.style.setProperty('--Background--', 'black');
      setTheme('dark');
    }else{
      root.style.setProperty('--Forground--', 'black');
      root.style.setProperty('--Background--', 'white');
      setTheme('light');
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className={navStyle.navbarDesign}>
        <div className={navStyle.logo}>
          <span className={navStyle.world}>World</span>
          <span className={navStyle.coder}>Coder</span>
          <span className={navStyle.master}>Master</span></div>
        <div className={navStyle.theme}>
          <i onClick={handleTheme} className={theme === 'light' ? `fa fa-sun ${navStyle.sunThemeIcon}` : `fa fa-moon ${navStyle.moonThemeIcon}`}></i>
        </div>
        <ul className={navStyle.listItems}>
          <li><Link className={navStyle.link} to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link className={navStyle.link} to="/service">Service</Link></li>
          <li><Link className={navStyle.link} to="/blog">Blog</Link></li>
          <li><Link className={navStyle.link} to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link className={navStyle.link} to="/">Login</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <div className={navStyle.searchGroup}>
          <input type="search" name="" id="" className={navStyle.navbarSearch} />
          <button className={navStyle.navbarSearchBtn}>Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).